# python finding the greatest common divisor of two numbers program

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new Python learner. I am trying to finding the greatest common divisor of two numbers (a =1071 and b = 462 for example). I have written two programs for this. the first one is working but the second one gives the wrong answer.  what is the problem with my program??

```
# first program (works)
a, b = 1071, 462
while b:
    a, b = b, a % b
print(a)

# second program (doesn't work truly)
a = 1071
b = 462
while b:
    a = b
    b = a % b
print(a)
```

Comment: The value of `a` is changed to `b` by the time `b = a % b` is evaluted. You're just running `b = b % b`.

Comment: Yes, you've changed the value of a to b in the second case so the valuation of b is wrong. You would better store it in some other variable then use it. In first it's being handled by the python itself.

Comment: Babak, you may want to *check* the answer you've accepted, *especially* if you're going to rely on it for classwork (no judgement there, but using code blindly is not going to do you any favours). While the answerer got the *concept* right, the code is currently dead wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**:
Yes, HSK is right. In the 2nd loop:

```
while b:
    a = b
    b = a % b
print(a)
```

First `a` is changed to `b` and then what you do is `b = b% b`. But here:

```
a, b = b, a % b
```

it is executed as one-line so `a` is still `a`.

---

**Solution**:
So just add a third variable:

```
a = 1071
b = 462
while b:
    c = a
    a = b
    b = c % b
print(c)
```

One thing that distinguishes Python from other programming languages is that it is interpreted rather than compiled. This means that it is executed line by line.

Comment: Gives wrong answer for `a = 2`, `b = 3`. The answer should be `1`, the program outputs `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The second doesn't work because, for the calculation of `b`, you need to use the *old* `a`, not the new `a` that got generated on the line before (this is actually set to `b` so you will get `b % b`, which will generally be zero). The equivalent to the first loop would be:

```py
while b:
    oldA = a
    a = b
    b = oldA % b

print(a)
```

The tuple assignment in Python can be considered an atomic operation where all the values on the right side are loaded up, *then* assigned to all the variables on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

```
def divisor(n):
  if n ==1 or n ==2 or n ==3:
    return []
  else:
    result=[]
    aux=2
    while aux <= n:
      if n % aux == 0:
         result.append(aux) 
      aux=aux+1
    return result

def func (m,n):
  div1=divisor(m)
  div2=divisor(n)
  result =[]
  for x in div1:
    for y in div2:
      if x == y:
        result.append(x)
  return result
print(func (x,y))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Zoe could you explain the reason of the rollback? This version has bugs. Neither it returns the `GCD`, nor it returns any divisor for input like: `x=2` and `y=4`.